# Apache could not access to copied folder: 403 Access Forbidden

Tags: permissions, apache2, webserver

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I have installed LAMP on Ubuntu and everything is OK but while I copy a folder into `/var/www` it is not accessible via URL. I have tried following commands:

```
sudo cp -r Desktop/site /var/www
sudo chown myuser /var/www -R 
sudo chmod 755 /var/www -R
```

Also:

```
sudo chown myuser /var/www/site -R 
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/site -R
```

I event don't see the folder while try list directories (`http://localhost/`). However, it's ok while I create a folder manually using `sudoo mkdir` command.

What should I do and what's the matter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some changes to Timo's helpful answer and a little more search, I solved it finally as below:

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo usermod -a -G <username> www-data
sudo chown :www-data /var/www -R
sudo chmod g+rwX /var/www -R
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Then re-login and now it's working!

Answer (score 2):

You have your syntax wrong. Try:

```
sudo chown -R <username> /var/www
```

or:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwX /var/www
```

but the most correct way would be:

```
sudo groupadd www
sudo useradd -g <username> www
sudo chown -R :www /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the ownership like this:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/site`

And then, change the directory permission like this:

`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`

Hope these help.